# How do I use the DataContract-based serializers for v0 requests to my api while using the default json/xml serializers for v1 requests to my api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I am in the process of migrating a WCF-based api to ASP.NET Core WebAPI-based api. I am also using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning` nuget package to provide "out of the box" api versioning for the WebAPI-based api.

Ideally, I would like to use the DataContract-based serializers for v0 request bodies and responses; thus, ensuring that the serialization works exactly like it currently does in the WCF-based api. However, for v1 request bodies and responses, I would prefer to use the newer, built-in json / xml serializers.

Is there an easy way to achieve this via settings in `Startup.cs` and using the `FormatFilter` attribute?

Comment: Are you expecting your *v1* web api to handle requests to the *v0* WCF endpoints?  What do your WCF endpoints URLs look like?

Comment: my WCF endpoints look something like:
`wcf?method=rawr&format=json&apikey=apikey&params=params`
my WebAPI endpoints look something like:
`webapi/controller/version/method?format=json&apikey=apikey&params=params`

I'm using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite` nuget on the WebAPI side to rewrite the WCF endpoint urls to the v0 WebAPI endpoints.

I have no desire to maintain a link between the WCF endpoint url format and v1 WebAPI endpoints. v1 WebAPI would be breaking changes, so clients would need to be updated to handle the new requests / responses; they can switch to new baseurl also.

Comment: I would recommend your rewriter do something like *www.mysite.com/api/v1/controller/version/method?format=json&apikey=apikey&params=params* to support the legacy WCF clients and introduce a new RESTful v2 to support new clients and add'l apis, so *www.mysite.com/api/v2/controller/action/etc*.  Does your WCF return json or SOAP today?

Comment: That's basically what I'm attempting to do; except v0 and v1 rather than v1 and v2. Yes, the WCF currently uses the DataContract Serializers to return json and xml which is why I want to use them for v0. I would prefer to use the default serializers for v1.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39272955/2779990 you may need a custom `MediaTypeFormatter`

Comment: Yeah, I had read that post. I don't really need "custom" so I was hoping that I could configure it without going down that route.

Comment: You're wanting to toggle the deserializer based on the entry point.  Are you wanting to use the same models/DTOs?  Not sure that'd be doable given the annotations, but...have you tried adorning your model with DataContract/Member *and* Json properties?

Comment: Yes, I would like to toggle the (de)serializer based on the entry point. While the current models do successfully work with both sets of serializers; they don't interop well due to namespace, ordering, casing and other small differences. I hadn't attempted to decorate the models with both sets of attributes as my original question seems way cleaner.

Comment: Not sure how many apis/clients you have, but it may be worth introducing a mapping layer for your legacy models that are mapped/converted to the new models (incoming/outgoing).  You could use something like a **DelegatingHandler** to facilitate that early in the pipline for incoming as an example.  At some point in the future if you sunset v0, then you just turn off/unplug the mapping layer.  Wish I had something more definitive man!